# Add missing paragraph tags to HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm processing some medium fancy HTML pages to convert to simpler XHTML ones. The source pages have several divs (that I'm removing), that contain text not inside `<p>` tags. I need to add these `<p>` tags.

Here is a minimal example of the source page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <div style="font-weight: bold;">
    This is a sample page
    <br/>
    Lots of things to learn!
    <p>And lots to test</p>
  </div>
  <p>Enough with the sample code</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to convert it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>This is a sample page</p>
  <p>Lots of things to learn!</p>
  <p>And lots to test</p>
  <p>Enough with the sample code</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm developing a python script using BeautifulSoup4 to do all the stuff. Now I'm stuck at this step. And it looks more like a regex job to locate the text to embed in `<p>` tags, and pass it to BeautifulSoup4. What do you think is the best approach to the problem?

I've scan several pages and I've seen these wild texts at the start of divs, but I can't exclude there will be several more around the pages in random places. (i.e. a script that checks at start of divs won't probably be reliable).

Notice the `<br/>` tags that has to be used to split the `<p>` paragraphs.

Comment: What have you tried? Add the snippet which is causing issue.

Comment: On this particular problem I didn't actually tried anything. I just have a couple of ideas (regex-based) to locate the text, but I already see their weakness in the real context (multiline paragraphs, not always start-of-div, <br/> in the way, ....). So I directly ask for the best approach (that maybe is not regex based but BeautifulSoup based (and I'm a noob with it))

Answer (score 1):

This script will remove all tags from `<body>` but `<p>` and then creates new paragraphs in place of `<br/>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <div style="font-weight: bold;">
    This is a sample page
    <br/>
    Lots of things to learn!
    <p>And lots to test</p>
  </div>
  <p>Enough with the sample code</p>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.body.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name != 'p'):
    tag.unwrap()

for txt in soup.body.find_all(text=True):
    if txt.find_parent('p') or txt.strip() == '':
        continue
    txt.wrap(soup.new_tag("p"))

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   Hello world!
  </p>
  <p>
   This is a sample page
  </p>
  <p>
   Lots of things to learn!
  </p>
  <p>
   And lots to test
  </p>
  <p>
   Enough with the sample code
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't actually want to remove everything. But I think this can be a good idea, that I can adapt to my case with a couple tweaks.

Comment: This won't work if the paragraph (without `<p>` tag) contains `<a>`links, `<span>`, ... Will have to use something different.